# Properly cleanup / teardown after instrumentation test only when app is 100% finished

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a bunch of end-to-end instrumentation tests (relying on Espresso) that start our launcher activity, then navigate throughout our app (eventually creating several activities). At the end of ***each*** test our `@After` annotated tear down method performs some cleanup.

The problem we have is that after the test finishes (successful or failed assertion) the app is still "running", so some of the cleanup is actually causing the app to crash. This is either resulting in false positives if the assert was successful, or hiding the test failure (we only see the crash not the failed assertion).

Here's an example:

```
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import com.example.SplashActivity;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SplashActivity> splashActivityTestRule
            = new ActivityTestRule<>(SplashActivity.class, true, false);

    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor splashActivityMonitor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        splashActivityMonitor = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(SplashActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
        getInstrumentation().addMonitor(splashActivityMonitor);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        // ... other test-specific setup before starting splash activity

        // start first activity
        splashActivityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());

        // a bunch of espresso steps that result in several other activities
        // ... creating and adding Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor for each one

        // assert something
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // clear shared prefs to prepare for next test
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
                .edit()
                .clear()
                .apply();

        // At this point the app is still running. Maybe a UI is still loading that was not relevant to the test, 
        // or some mock web request is in flight. But at some point after the final assert in our test, the app needs
        // to get something from shared prefs, which we just cleared, so the app crashes.
    }
}
```

As you can see, the app is still running during the tear down method. Any changes we make to the state of the app here may cause the app to crash.

So how can I assert that the app is dead and gone *before* doing this cleanup?

Some possible (but ugly) solutions I've come up with:

After the final assert, continue to navigate back to some neutral point in the app (i.e use espresso to logout and return to splash screen). This should work but it'll add a lot of other steps to *every* test. Also I'm not sure this will work if the assert fails.

Or perform some sort of app kill in the teardown:

```
public void tearDown() {
    // finish all tasks before cleaning up
    ActivityManager activityManager =
            (ActivityManager) InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
    for (ActivityManager.AppTask appTask : appTasks) {
        appTask.finishAndRemoveTask();
    }

    // clear shared prefs to prepare for next test
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
            .edit()
            .clear()
            .apply();
}
```

---

Update:

I know I can use `ActivityTestRule.afterActivityFinished()` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#afterActivityFinished()) but I don't think this will work for *multiple* actvities.

Comment: You could try System.exit(); before clearing shared preferences but there is no gaurentee that the prefs will be modified. Additionally it may just kill the entire app.

Comment: @tir38, I want my bounty :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem you described can be solved by using `AndroidTestOrchestrator`. From the official Android documentation:

> When using `AndroidJUnitRunner` version 1.0 or higher, you have access
>   to a tool called Android Test Orchestrator, which allows you to run
>   each of your app's tests within its own invocation of Instrumentation.

Application under test will be cleaned after each test run automatically.

`build.gradle` file sample with `AndroidTestOrchestrator` enabled:

1. Using `AndroidTestOrchestrator` with Android support library - [github link](https://github.com/Apress/android-espresso-revealed/blob/master/app/build.gradle)
2. Using `AndroidTestOrchestrator` with AndroidX Test library - [github link](https://github.com/Apress/android-espresso-revealed/blob/androidx-espresso-revealed/app/build.gradle)

Official Android documentation - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner).

Comment: LOL. When we first added Orchestrator to our project we saw it wasn't clearing shared prefs as referenced here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-testing-support-library/VUT97mrwWQY and here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77549481 I *swear* at one point the official docs even said that you still had to manually clear shared prefs and reset any databases. Looking at the docs now I can't find this, nor can I find any reference to shared prefs when looking at the docs via the Wayback Machine. Oh well I'll try now to see if `clearPackageData` is actually working

Comment: Thanks so much for this @denys, Orchestrator was just what I needed (to clear state between test runs).

Answer (score 1):

a) one could either set default preferences instead of blanking them -

b) or use the shared resource itself, to prevent the race condition:

```
public static final String PREFERENCE_KEY_TEST_COUNT = "testCount";
public static final int MAX_TEST_COUNT = 6;

@After
public void tearDown() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()):
    if(prefs.getPreference(PREFERENCE_KEY_TEST_COUNT, 0) >= MAX_TEST_COUNT) {
        prefs.edit().clear().apply();
    } else {
        int testCount = prefs.getPreference(PREFERENCE_KEY_TEST_COUNT, 0) + 1;
        prefs.edit().putInt(PREFERENCE_KEY_TEST_COUNT, testCount).apply();
    }
}
```

c) or [Test Suite](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/aggregating-tests-in-suites) and a custom `Runner` could be used to control the tests; this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners) explains it.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I need to run this cleanup after *each* test.

Comment: @tir38 the issue, as you describe it, sounds alike a race condition on a shared resource. blanking the `SharedPreferences` causes it and the annotations might not suffice to determine the proper moment, when to blank them (the one test does not know of the other) - the only efficient way to prevent the race condition might be either a) setting values to defaults (appears most solid) or b) adding a default set of preferences, once blanked (there still is the risk of access while blanked). while actually... one could even use `SharedPreference` to indicate the state of tests to the other test.