# How do i relaunch application from start for every individual test case in Espresso Android

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a testsuite which has mutiple testcases in a class
every test case is isolated
So when i execute the testsuite class i want to restart the app for every testcase

How do i relaunch application from start for every individual test case in Espresso

Thanks in advance

```
@Test
public void testcase1() {
//from first screen
}

@Test
public void testcase2() {
//from first screen
}
```

Comment: Similar question was answered by me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079434/properly-cleanup-teardown-after-instrumentation-test-only-when-app-is-100-fin/54163572#54163572

Answer (score 0):

There is another [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198750) answer that seems to answer this question. If you were looking to do that in Kotlin though I converted the answer to relaunch multiple times for different tests.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleEspressoTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = ActivityTestRule(
        activityClass = MainActivity::class.java,
        initialTouchMode = false,
        launchActivity = false) //set to false to customize intent

    @Test
    fun testCustomIntent() {
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra("your_key", "your_value")
        }
        rule.launchActivity(intent)

        //continue with your test
    }

}
```

Comment: I have multiple cases in single suite and all are independent
 Test
    public void testcase1() {
 //from first screen
 }
 
 Test
    public void testcase2() {
 //from first screen
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start a method/test and when it's finished clear data and start the next one, you should use commands.

Look at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

I'm using this command:

```
./gradlew testVariantNameUnitTest --tests *.sampleTestMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be several ways to do this but we wanted a way that works both locally as well as google fire base test lab, so ended up with using configuration in `build.gradle` file under default config.

```
defaultConfig{ 
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-gradle

Also you use these runner arguments for configuring different tests you wanted run based on build variants or other config options, look at my [post](https://medium.com/@satyajit/running-subset-of-espresso-tests-locally-and-gcloud-4713931da56) if you want more detail.